# Putting on weight, gaining weight, getting fat

Tags: meaning

Which is the correct sentence or what is difference between the following sentences?

1. My friend is putting on weight.
2. My friend is gaining weight.
3. My friend is getting fat.

Comment: They're all apt to cause your friend to slap you, but the third is probably the worst in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend is "putting on weight", they may be doing it intentionally - like a body-builder. This way of saying "increasing in mass" is the most easily construed as a positive - although it may also be negative.

"Gaining weight" is neutral, and may be taken in a positive or negative sense, depending on whether your friend is too thin or too fat.

These first two are relatively polite.

"Getting fat" is definitely not polite, and almost always negative.